# Java - How do i close myself and restart myself, such as my software kernel panic and i need reboot itself?

Tags: java, windows, executable-jar

I have a case, where i need to do `System.exit(0);` and then immediately restart the same application on kernel panic or something like that. But if i call System.exit(0) first how do i call the exec() ? Like in linux i got it working with BASH.

```
#!/bin/bash
pkill java;
sleep 1;
java -cp /var/tmp/dist/Kernel.jar main.Kernel
```

Main.java:

```
/* Windows platform running */
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    // other activity happening.... for ages

    // 
    // Suddently there will be a kernel panic it is better to do a software reboot 
    // remotely
    //
  }

  public static rebootSoftwareKernel()
  {
    System.exit(0); // Exit completely
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec( MyConstant.RunItSelfSoftReboot() ); // Restart this same 
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you run the reboot before calling exit?  For a brief moment, is it possible to start up the new process *before* shutting down the old?  Also, is pkill the best option? What if there are other Java processes running?

Comment: When i call `exec(); System.exit(0);` its not sync. Because exec is executing the same active instance, can not be duplicated. So its failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [Tanuki Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/). Among other features it allows to restart the JVM when needed.